# How to load store via POST request

Tags: extjs, cross-domain

I need to load store via cross domain POST request

```
Ext.define('MyDesktop.desktop.store.DesktopShortcutStore', {


  extend: 'Ext.data.Store',


  requires: [
    'MyDesktop.desktop.model.DesktopShortcutModel'
  ],


  constructor: function(cfg) {
    var me = this;
    cfg = cfg || {};
    me.callParent([Ext.apply({
      storeId: 'DesktopShortcutStore',
      model: 'MyDesktop.desktop.model.DesktopShortcutModel',
      autoLoad: false,
      proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: getApiUrl() + 'account/desktop-shortcuts-list',
        cors: true,
        reader: {
          type: 'json',
          rootProperty: 'items',
          successProperty: 'success'
        },
        paramsAsJson: true,
        actionMethods: {
          read: 'POST'
        },
        extraParams: {
          fff: 'zzz'
        }
      }
    }, cfg)]);
  }


});
```

But I have OPTIONS request with no "fff" param.

Cross domain via jQuery is working correctly.

Using

```
Ext.Ajax.useDefaultXhrHeader = false;
Ext.Ajax.cors = true;
```

Is not helps.

I cannot find any information in docs.

Comment: Usually a pre-flight request (OPTIONS) does not need extra headers, as it just checks if the server allows the origin. When the pre-flight turns out to be "legal", the actual POST follows.

Comment: A quick & easy way to load your store via POST is to use Ext.Ajax.request and parse the response yourself or use the JSON response property. Then iterate through the records and load into the store.

Comment: I believe you can't do an Ajax request to a different domain @BenjaminE. (due to  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) that's why he is using CORS. Another option is to use JSONP proxy, indapublic (though should be possible to use CORS)

Comment: @code4jhon Of course you can do CORS with Ajax. All modern browsers support it according to the spec (IE10+). But it needs proper configuration on both client & server.

Comment: Well I guess I'm getting old :P, Ok didn't know that ...

Comment: @BenjaminE. I have correct server working with Access-Control-Allow-Origin (jQuery requests are working successfully).

Answer (score 0):

This should be the easiest solution. Loading a store directly via a proxy and POST might require a few overrides, not sure it's worth the effort (needs more investigation).

```
var store = ...;

Ext.Ajax.request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '...',
    withCredentials: true, // for identity cookies
    success: function(response) {
        // given json array is returned
        var data = Ext.decode(response.responseText);

        Ext.each(data, function(r) {
            store.add(r);
        });
    }
});
```